# Transforming shapefile to WGS:84 (EPSG: 4326) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I received several shapefiles from an colleague that he told me is in WGS:84. If I look at the metadata in Qgis it tells me the following:

```
In layer spatial reference system units
xMin,yMin 3572722.82,5453423.31 : xMax,yMax 3582448.25,5462926.22
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Now when I try to save it in another projection say WGS:84 Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857) it gives me the following:

```
 Export to vector file failed.
    Error: Failed to transform a point while drawing a feature with ID '1'. Writing stopped. (Exception: forward transform of
    (62425.896446, 95242.109906)
    PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs
    Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits)
```

A similar message is returned in R with the rgdal package. I suspect that the initial projection is somehow wrong.

Is it truly WGS84?

The problem occurs with all shapefiles.

```
ogrinfo -so
```

tells me:

```
INFO: Open of `XXX.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: XXXABC (Polygon)
```

Comment: From which country is your data ?

Comment: South-Western part of Germany

Comment: Did you already try to just assign DHDN GK 3 to your data? Cause coordinates like 3572722.82,5453423.31 perfectly fit to that region.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Sorry if my question appeared stupid but I am kind of new with all these things. If you like, you can put your last sentence as an answer and I will give you the credit for it.

Comment: No, not stupid at all. Thing like this happen quite often, and coordinate systems are really weird stuff!

Comment: +1 for including sample coordinates and the location of the data!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data seems not to be in WGS84, but in a metric system as you can see from the metadata you posted.

The xmin/ymin coordinates 3572722/5453423 have 7 digits both, while coordinates in WGS84 are much smaller (from -180 to 180 degrees).

If your coordinates would have 6 digits and 7 digits, it could be e.g. a UTM projection.
Furthermore, your first coordinate starts with a 3 and you said that your data is from south-east Germany, so my conclusion is, that your data is still projected in DHDN Gauss-Krüger 3 (EPSG 31467).

These coordinates in WGS 84 would be something like 12.2/49.8.

If, and *only if*, the layer currently has a *wrong CRS assigned* to its coordinate values: **Right-click** on the layer in the **Layers** list and choose **Set Layer CRS**. Then pick the appropriate CRS from the list or search with the filter.

To reproject your layer then to WGS84, you have to **right-click**, use **Save As ...** and click on **Change...** behind the current CRS to pick another one and then press OK to create a new copy of your data with that new CRS.

A little more info on your DHDN Gauss-Krüger 3 data:
This is a metric system, so the coordinates tell you the offset from a reference meridian in meters. Gauss-Krüger is divided in 3-degree zones, so your reference meridian for GK 3 is 3 * 3 = 9. Actually your offset from that meridian is ca. 72.7 km to the east, but in Gauss-Krüger 3 there are 500.000m added. -> 3 | 500000 + 72722 -> 3572722. The y-coordinate shows to norther offset from the equator as reference line in meters, so around 5423 km from there.

Comment: minor point, WGS84 is not 0 to 180 but -180 to 180

Comment: rrright! corrected