# Converting from EPSG 25833 to WGS 4326 using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, wgs84

I have a layer of Brandenburg (Germany) in EPSG 25833 which I want to tranfrom to EPSG 4326. Similar to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127750/115) to [Transforming shapefile to WGS:84 (EPSG: 4326) in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127739), I set the CRS to EPSG 4326 and go to *export / save as* to save this layer in 4326.

Now once I try to overlay this layer with a point shapefile of hospitals in Brandenburg taken from OSM (which is in EPSG 4326 by default) they do not match at all.

What am I missing?

[image: Brandenburg Layer in EPSG 25833]
[image: Brandenburg Layer in EPSG 4326]

Comment: The currect suggestion of being a duplicate is invalid, at least for the suggested other question. That one is an answer to a problem that probably led to this, but not to this actual question. :)

Comment: Which steps exactly did you do to to the Brandenburg layer?

Comment: 1. Rather reproject the OSM-data to 25833 than the other way round, since the BB-layer should be official data. 2. Do not "set" the CRS to something different, only save the data using a different CRS. Seems like QGIS thinks your BB-layer has degree-values in the range of 300k and above. 3. Rather enable `on the fly reprojection` for simple visual overlaying.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191332/shapefile-disappeared-after-changing-crs